# Not sure how to notate this

Tags: notation, tuplet, tremolo

I'm not sure if this is a sextuplet with a tremolo or how to notate it. (Using Musescore; I know how to notate a sextuplet with a tremolo, but it doesn't look like this once I do). Any advice as to what it is and how to notate would be appreciated!
[image: sextuplet with tremolo?]

Comment: As a clarification, you're looking for three repetitions of each note within each sextuplet?

Comment: Unless the tempo is extremely slow this will be indistinguishable from a trill, and a trill would be much easier to read.

Comment: What piece is this from? It doesn't look like your own composition.

Comment: What is the source of this notation?  I've never seen flags or flat signs like this before.  The colored bar line and ties are also interesting.

Comment: This is **BAD** notation.  the 3 bars indicate tremolo, but the "6" contradicts that.  IIRC the notation should be  2bars, with the "6" being redundant.    WARNING: you haven't shown the  meter for the piece; we're all guessing that it's 6/8 or 12/8  but if it isn't, ....     Further,  three dotted eighths do not equal one dotted quarter, so even the fundamental markings are incorrect.

Comment: @phoog - I think I've seen flat signs like this before in some Kapustin sheet music or maybe some other vaguely classical-leaning Third Stream composer's sheet music.

Answer (score 2):

The musical result will be this:
[image]

Here's how to do it in MuseScore.   Enter all 6 notes as a sextuplet.  Edit the 1st and 3rd to be dotted 16ths.  Apply the trem.

[image]